# Adding an offset to a Leaflet TileLayer on the fly

Tags: leaflet

I'm currently using Leaflet to display 18th century maps of Belgium as a base layer with a vector overlay of the present day road system. Although the maps are absolutely gorgeous (http://www.ngi.be/NL/NL1-4-2-3 if you're interested), map production techniques were less than ideal back then, which means some streets are seriously offset from their real positions.

What I'd like to do, is have the users drag only the 18th century base layer so they can report what offset fits a particular present day street the best.

In the following snapshot, you can see present day roads in blue, with its 18th century equivalents shifted southwards:
[image]

I'd like to temporarily drag the base layer to have the road match up somewhat to get a rough estimation of the maps (lack of) accuracy for that particular road.

It's a rather peculiar use-case, and unsurprisingly I haven't found an existing solution. I know it's possible to offset layers using [Proj4Leaflet](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet), but that seems to be at layer creation, not on the fly.

Does anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this? I'm quite well-versed in Javascript/HTML, so I'm not afraid to get my hands dirty with Leaflet internals; I currently just don't have a clue where to begin. I'd rather not move the vector layer, since there are other base layers that do match up.

Comment: Those look _really_ neat. Perhaps instead of dragging, they could manually type in an offset and click a button which triggers some JavaScript to redraw the layer with that offset?

Comment: @Erica: they really are a sight to behold! Typing an offset would indeed be easier, because I can just recreate the layer. It would, however, take some time consuming guess work to get it right. In the near future, this kind of thing will be done in bulk with thousands of roads and other features, so it should be fast and easy. If there's no other alternative, I'll probably do it that way. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I still haven't learned L.Draggable in Leaflet, but can recommend checking out [my plugin](https://github.com/Zverik/leaflet-bing-iodb/blob/gh-pages/Bing.IODB.js#L54) for offsetting a tiled layer. Basically I shift a container div using CSS.